# Django subdomains unexpected behaviour

Tags: django, nginx, subdomain, django-subdomains

My two subdomains aren't routing correctly.

Here is my middleware class

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'subdomains.middleware.SubdomainURLRoutingMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
```

As you can see SubdomainURL Routing middleware is above Common.

The configuration is like so:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'deltaforce.urls'

SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS = {
    'api': 'errorPage.urls',
    None: 'interface.urls',
}
```

The issue is both abc.com and api.abc.com are routing to the None/`interface.urls`.

I came to know about the same from the 404 page on each. The difference between `deltaforce.urls` and `interface.urls` is the default admin console which is not showing up which is a good sign that it is not using `ROOT_URLCONF` but the `api` is also showing similar behavior as the only page in error page is 404 which i am using to test it out. It's 404 page is showing a list of urls from interface.

Here is something else that might be important:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".abc.com"]
```

`abc.com` and other subdomains are there is a `/etc/hosts` file and finally this is all behind an nginx proxy which passes host headers properly based on requested url on 404 page.